# Integrating the "open with" menu in my iPhone application

Tags: ios, file-type, file-type-associations

There seems to me many tutorials on how to associate files to an application, but I cannot find any information on how to open a file from my application using the iOS registered applications of that file type.

What I want is to give the user, inside my own app, the same "open-with" menu that you can find, for example, in Apple's Mail applicaton - is there any Apple API I can use for this?

Looking at an application like Dropbox, I can see they have implemented a similar feature - so there must be a way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [1], Document interaction, Previewing and opening files. Once you have an instance of `UIDocumentInteractionController` (using `interactionControllerWithURL:` and setting your delegate) you can use that to present the open menu, for example by using `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:`. If you provide a delegate you can also use that to supply a view for previewing the foreign document.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1